# How to add 2 axis parameters in power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to view columngraph by month grouped by year the way shown in the image.How can i do it n power bi desktop
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkaCH.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Below is the sample table used in this example :

   [Sample Table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqVxb.jpg)
2. In Power BI desktop, add ‘Stacked Column Chart’
3. In Axis, Place ‘Year’ first and then followed by ‘Month’
4. In Legend, place ‘Brand’
5. In the Value, place the ‘cost’ or ‘value’

   [chart parameters picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkjGd.jpg)
6. Click on ‘Expand all down one level in the hierarchy’ in the chart

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8uni.png)
7. Then, go to ‘Format’ pane

[Format Chart Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRAHy.png)

8. Expand ‘X-Axis’
9. Set ‘Concatenate Labels’ to Off.

[Concatenate labels off picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVi5H.png)